# Question on Taylor series in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
e^{-1/x^2} & \text{if }x\ne 0, \\ 0 & \text{if }x=0.
\end{cases}
$$
How do I prove that $(d/dx)f$ at $0$??
I tried it this way,
\begin{align}
f'(0) & = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}x \\[10pt]
& = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}x;
\end{align}
Now if I use L'hospital rule, I get  again $0/0$ form,which remains regardless of how many times ,I apply L'hospital rule. ^_^

If I use expansion for $e^{-1/x^2}$, even then limit shouldn't exist.But as per book, $f'(0)$ exists and equals $0$.
Can anyone please help? I'll be very grateful to them. 
PS: I don't know how to type maths symbols like- limit tending to some value.So please don't mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x} = \lim_{t\to \infty} te^{-t^2}$$

Since $e^y \ge 1 + y$ for all $y \ge 0$ (by the mean value theorem), then $e^{-y} \le \frac{1}{1 + y}$ for all $y \ge 0$. Consequently,

$$0 \le te^{-t^2} \le \frac{t}{1 + t^2}$$

for all $t \ge 0$. Since $\frac{t}{1 + t^2} \to 0$ as $t\to \infty$, by the squeeze theorem, $\lim_{t\to \infty} te^{-t^2} = 0$. So $f'(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

let $\dfrac{1}{x}=u$ then calculate $\lim\limits_{u\to\infty} ue^{-u^2}=\lim\limits_{u\to\infty} \dfrac{u}{e^{u^2}}=o$.

Comment: @Mchael Hardy thank you very much for edit